# How to move some mails from Outlook.com to free up some space while keeping the complete conversation view in Outlook of Office?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email, microsoft-office, onedrive, outlook.com

Due to the recent policy changes to the Outlook.com, i.e. 5GB limit on attachment, my email account is running out of space online, and I’m thinking to move some mails offline to free up some space.

If I create a new .pst file in Outlook and move my old mails there, the conversation view of some email thread would be incomplete as it only includes mails in all folders in the same .ost file. If I just move my old mails to a new folder in the same .ost file to keep the conversation view complete, I cannot prevent Outlook from uploading the content of the new folder, thus it won’t solve the space problem.

Any suggestions to solve my issue?  I’m not using subscription-based office 365, thus my email space is quite limited.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to get what you are asking for, for the reasons you've already presented. Can Search Folders view content from multiple mail files? If it can, you might be able to get that here, but without that, I don't think there's a chance.

Comment: @music2myear, just bring *all* messages local, as they arrive.

Comment: You're right....

Comment: You can move your old mails to a new folder in a new .pst file instead of the same .ost file. This way, you can keep the conversation view complete and prevent Outlook from uploading the content of the new folder. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-an-outlook-data-file-pst-to-save-your-information-17a13ca2-df52-48e8-b933-4c84c2aabe7c#:~:text=How%20to%20Create%20a%20PST%20File%201%20On,the%20Password%20and%20Verify%20Password...%20.%20See%20More.

Comment: @Faery Do you mean to move it once or keep moving as new mails coming in?

Answer (score 1):

Put the email you wish to keep in **local** folders, i.e., only on your own computer. This can be done using [Internet Message Access Protocol, IMAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol) protocol, rather than [Post Office Protocol, POP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol). *Then* delete the messages from the server. This can be done automatically, so the whole conversation thread is stored locally.

With POP, your messages stay on the mail server, and to read them, you download a temporary copy. With IMAP, the mail is transferred to your machine, and can be copied to an offline, local, folder. Once the messages have been downloaded and copied to a local folder, you can delete them permanently from the server. The *entire* conversation thread can be maintained on the local machine, and you can still reply to or forward those messages, even though they're local.

There are many mail readers, such as free Mozilla [Thunderbird](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/). that make it easy to set up local folders, as shown below. There are directions for setting this up [online](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thunderbird-and-hotmail).

[image: Thunderbird local folders]

Not only can the local folders hold messages from Outlook.com, you can include accounts from GMail, Mail.com and elsewhere.

If you have multiple devices, set up IMAP email on all, and download the messages to all, so there are copies on all machines, before deleting them from Outlook.com.

You can even create rules in each Thunderbird *Inbox* such that when a message arrives, it is copied to the correct local folder. You can have different rules on a PC at work and one at home.  A rule *could* delete the mail in the *Inbox*, after copying it, if you're running short of space, but personally, I'd prefer to do that myself after reading it and confirming that I've a local copy.

Comment: I want to keep as many emails online as possible for easy access. Though I can achieve the same goal by having a copy on each device, but smartphone can easily run out of space if I choose to do so.